# Jackson 1.x to 2.x and the meaning of backwards compatibility

Tags: json, jackson

By necessity, I need to upgrade from Jackson 1.x to 2.x.  After reading the notes on the release, I thought it would be fine to upgrade, so long as I made the necessary code changes:

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonRelease20

However, I realized after-the-fact that I still need to be able to deserialize data serialized with 1.x versions in the event that we have pre-upgrade data data flowing back into the service, which is guaranteed to happen.

Is Jackson 2.x suited to this or not?  I understand that 2.x requires recompile, but can it still handle the old serialized format?

Comment: Json is json. Unless you've been customizing a lot, there is no 'difference in format'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, your case is that data serialized with Jackson 1, will be read by Jackson 2, this shouldn't be a problem at all, since both understand JSON format.

There is a possibility you have customizations based on annotation and hierarchies, even if this is the case, almost everything is supported in Jackson 1, should be supported in Jackson 2 (this is where backwards compatibility plays a role).

In the remote case you have something that only can be deserialized with Jackson 1, you can still do a rolling upgrade in your project, the Jackson guys did an amazing job in this scenario, where they changed all packages name to `com.fasterxml.jackson` from the old `org.codehaus.jackson`, this means that both version can live in your classpath, allowing you to upgrade things based on priorities, or incrementally.

I have experience in the 3 scenarios I mentioned, since our projects used to use Jackson 1 and now we moved all of them to the latest and greatest.

Hope this helps,

Jose Luis

Comment: "In the remote case you have something that only can be deserialized with Jackson 1" - Is there an example of this?

Comment: What do you mean by only serialized with Jackson 1? Are you planning to migrate the DTO to jackson 2? @SalientSage

Comment: I was referring to your statement (3 para 1st line) and trying to understand what can be examples of cases where a data serialized with 1 can only be deserialized with 1.